# Azure MSSQL to GCP Cloud SQL (MSSQL) - Migrate symmetric keys and Certificates

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, google-cloud-sql

We have encrypted certain columns in our Azure MS-SQL database with our symmetric keys/certificates

```sql
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY JanainaKey09   
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256  
ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Shipping04;  
GO
```

We have more than 100,000 records and now looking to migrate to GCP Cloud SQL for SQL Server(MSSQL Engine) and need to migrate the symmetric key and certificates also, along with the data. How to do it? There are a few suggestions to create new keys and certs in the new environment which will pose us a challenge that existing data cannot be decrypted at all.

How to migrate keys and certs also? please help guide

Comment: Have you looked at customer-managed encryption keys at all? https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/cmek

Comment: Hi, have you resolved the issue yet?

Comment: Nope. I haven't resolved it. Still trying to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

If you have encrypted the entire database then can import the data with the keys and certificate using an encrypted BAK file. You need to first create an [Encrypted backup file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/create-an-encrypted-backup?view=sql-server-ver15).
Then you can upload that file to Google Cloud Storage. Later you can use `gcloud beta sql import bak` [CLI command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/sql/import/bak) to import with the certificate and private key.

You can refer [Export and import using BAK files](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/import-export/import-export-bak#import_data_from_a_bak_file) for steps in detail.

If you have encrypted certain columns on SQL, then Google Cloud KMS service should help you. You can refer to [Column level encryption in GCP](https://dzone.com/articles/column-level-encryption-and-gcp) for the steps and process of how to do it.